# If I use appendChild() with an element that's not yet appended to the DOM, will it cause reflow?

Tags: javascript, web

For example, in this code , does the line `myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);` cause reflow ?
I think it doesn't, since the element is not yet appended to the DOM, but I read somewhere that it does cause a reflow, so why does that happen ?

```
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
  const newElement = document.createElement('p');
  newElement.innerText = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
  myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);
```

Comment: *Reflow* of what exactly?

Comment: DOM reflow, the browser makes calculations to display the correct layout.

Comment: Then why are you asking about something that has nothing to do with DOM?

Comment: how is exactly is appending elements to the DOM irrelevant to the DOM

Comment: In your code, the reflow would not happen until `document.body.appendChild()`

Comment: Your words "*since the element is not yet appended to the DOM*".

Comment: @LilDevil alright thanks! For some reason the course on Udacity said otherwise and I thought it was wrong about it.

Comment: @Mohamed Rady Well, it may not be wrong. If `myCustomDiv` is appended to the `body` **first,** then subsequently executing `myCustomDiv.appendChild()` will cause a reflow.